# Neato Lidar to Raspberry Pi?

Tags: gpio, usb

How would one connect the neato lidar to the raspberry pi? I know that there are a lot of choices, such as GPIO or USB (with [this](http://www.getsurreal.com/product/xv-lidar-controller-v1-2)?), but which one is the best with the least latency? I would love for a through tutorial on this, as I cannot seem to find one on the internet. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Using Neato LIDAR with your embedded board](https://web.archive.org/web/20150326122026/http://profmason.com/?p=13246), it looks like the LIDAR is 3.3 V TTL serial at 115200 bps. You should be able to use the UART built into the GPIO to control it.

You will have to be a bit careful with the power lines, as I'm almost positive that the Raspberry Pi's 3.3 V GPIO can't deliver the current that the sensor needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you think I should use the USB to power the LIDAR or use some external power supply?

Comment: You'll need around 200 mA, so external would be safer.